# How to limit elements in stream to maximum number?

Tags: java

Let's consider following stream in java:
`(a,a,b,b,b,b,a,a,a,b,c,c,c,e,c,d,d,c,c,c,c,d)` and `k=3`.

I would like to get following result (order doesn't matter):
`(a,a,b,b,b,a,c,c,c,e,d,d,d)`

So something like eliminating duplicates with allowing to `k` duplicates in stream.
How to do it in elegant way?

Comment: By creating your own `Collector` that checks it the result already contains the maximum amount.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a HashMap to collect the counters of each element:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String[] inputArray = {"a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "c", "e", "c", "d", "d", "c", "c", "c", "c", "d"};
        int k = 3;

        List<String> outputArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        for (String element : inputArray) {
            Integer count = map.get(element);

            // If the limit has not been reached
            if (count == null || count < k) {
                outputArray.add(element);

                // Count the number of occurences
                if (count == null) {
                    count = 1;
                } else {
                    count++;
                }
                map.put(element, count);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Result=" + outputArray);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(new String[] {
                "a","a","b","b","b","b","a","a","a","b","c","c","c","e","c","d","d","c","c","c","c","d"
        });

        final int k = 3;
        Map<String, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<>();

        List<String> result = list.stream().map(item -> {
            if(countMap.containsKey(item)) {
                countMap.put(item, countMap.get(item) + 1);
            } else {
                countMap.put(item, 1);
            }

            return item;
        }).filter(item -> countMap.containsKey(item) && countMap.get(item) <= k).collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

Comment: You could use `peek` instead of `map` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
        int k = 3;
        Map<String, Integer> count = new HashMap<>();
        String[] test = {"a","a","b","b","b","b","a","a","a","b","c","c","c","e","c","d","d","c","c","c","c","d"};
        List<String> fin = Arrays.stream(test).map(ch -> {
            if (count.containsKey(ch)) {
                count.put(ch, count.get(ch) + 1);
            } else {
                count.put(ch, 1);
            }
            return ch;
        }).filter(ch -> count.get(ch) <= k+1).collect(Collectors.toList());
```